# MVVM message not received when sending from another ViewModel

Tags: c#, uwp, mvvm-light

I have created a detail page containing some quiz questions. I need to send the list of questions to the ViewModel. The data in the receiving ViewModel is always emtpy. The debuger doesn't even go into the 'ReceiveMessage' method.
Here is my sending part:

```
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        Messenger.Default.Send<List<QuizQuestion>>(this.Questions);
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(QuestionOverviewPage));
```

And here is my receiving viewmodel:

```
    public QuestionOverviewViewModel(IMessageDialogService dialogService, IRoundRepository rounRepository)
    {
        _dialogService = dialogService;
        _rounRepository = rounRepository;
        _quizQuestionsViewModels = new List<QuestionViewModel>();
        Messenger.Default.Register<List<QuizQuestion>>
        (
            this,ReceiveMessage
        );
    }

    private void ReceiveMessage(List<QuizQuestion> action)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(action);
    }
```

Comment: Did `QuestionOverviewViewModel` method call before `Send` question list?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I debugged it. The `rootFrame.Navigate` triggers a page swap. So the `Messenger.Default.Send<List<QuizQuestion>>(this.Questions);` is being called first.

Comment: I mean   `Messenger.Default.Register<List<QuizQuestion>>` has invoked before send message?

Comment: `Messenger.Default.Register` should be invoked before sending, this steps will pass the subscriber to sub-list and send client will find the instance then call action method with parameter.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT The `Messenger.Default.Register` is not invoked before the send. But I don't know how to do this. Beceause i can only declare it inside the receiving ViewModel. I cannot declare it in another ViewModel. That has no knowledge of the other VIewModel and it's method `ReceiveMessage`.

Comment: I found you place the `Messenger.Default.Register` in the `QuestionOverviewViewModel`, and the `Send` method called before  `rootFrame.Navigate`, So you could try to call send method after `rootFrame.Navigate`.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT You are my hero! Thank you very much. This fixed the problem. I thought the `rootFrame.Navigate` would stop the current VIewModel. So all the code after it wouldn't be called. But it seems that is not to be the case.

Comment: No bother guys, May I convert above steps as answer for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MVVM message not received when sending from another ViewModel

`Messenger.Default.Register` should be invoked before sending, this step will pass the subscriber to sub-list and send client will find the subscriber  instance then call action method with parameter.

I found you place the `Messenger.Default.Register` in the QuestionOverviewViewModel, and the Send method called before `rootFrame.Navigate`, So you could try to call send method after `rootFrame.Navigate`.

```
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;       
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(QuestionOverviewPage));
Messenger.Default.Send<List<QuizQuestion>>(this.Questions);
```